# Optional date and month in date field in Laravel

Tags: laravel, date, eloquent, model, laravel-6

I have a Photo model that contains information about a historical photo, including date of photography. Often we do not know exactly which day the photo has been taken, but only the month or year. Is there some way to solve this without having three database fields for date, month and year.

Answer (score 1):

date("m-Y",strtotime($date));

I think this could work. Let me know if it helped.

You can enter a date with a random day. It will cut it out.